# Add action to AjaxBehaviorEvent event

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, seam, seam2

Currently I am working on a spring migration project. Since a4j:support is no longer supported I had to change those tags to a4j:ajax tags, but a4j:ajax tags do not have the action attribute. The systems is currently very heavily based on a seam pageflow which depend heavily on actions for it's navigation rules.

I was wondering if anyone knew an easy way in which I could just add an action to a AjaxBehaviorEvent so that I could pass in a value for the pageflow navigation? I have attempted to call the seam navigation handler directly and I keep getting a pageflow not initiated exception.

Here is an example of one of our pageflow pages if that helps

```
<page view-id="/customerProfileSetup.xhtml" 
    name="readProfile">
    <redirect/>
    <transition name="readProductProfileSetup"
        to="productProfileSetup">
        <action
            expression="#{profileSetup.load}" />
    </transition>
</page>
```

Ajax tag:

```
<a4j:ajax  event="change" render="@all" listener="#{pageflowUtil.processPageflowAjaxBehavior}"/>
```

Method:

```
public void processPageflowAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {}
```

Comment: If you can use `a4j:jsFunction`, then there is `action` attribute.

Comment: I know but I don't want to have to add like 1000 jsf functions to the code in order to get it to work. This is used a many different places.